# column exist on table

Tags: delphi

Hi I am using Delphi7 with Oracle ODBC I am working on "Testing knowledge" program.
I want to insert a table if the column doesn't exist.

I can do this :

I have 5 buttons(A,B,C,D,E).

If I click on A ..

I use...

1) adoquery1 sql to..

```
ALTER TABLE test
ADD COLUMN col1 INT
```

2) adoquery2 sql to insert....

then I click next to change question     it works good
but when I return previous question I want to see all 5 buttons visible=false because this question have been answered

How can I do this? therefore I need to find column exist on table or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean

```
Button1.Visible := not Assigned(myDataSet.FindField('col1'));
```

?

Comment: I mean if col1 exist on table test then alter tabel ..... else the buttons visible:=false

Comment: Well, `FindField` returns the field (column) if it exits in the dataset.  If not, it returns `nil`.  Be aware that when you execute a sql-statement directly to the DB, all datasets that are connected to that table must be refreshed/updated to reflect the changes in the DB.  I wouldn't recommend that you use this approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a really bad idea. Routine operations in an application shouldn't be creating new fields in database tables. They should be creating new **records**, or adding data to exiting **fields**. No "ALTER TABLE" commands should be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

if we have deal with MS SQL Server the query can be like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from syscolumns where Name = N'Col1' and id = OBJECT_ID('Test','U'))
    ALTER TABLE Test ADD [col1] [int]
```

if Field col1 not exists in table Test, the query will add it to table